# querySelector or addEventListener is not working with electron in html

Tags: html, node.js, electron, alert, addeventlistener

I've started a desktop project with electron. But my button is not working, no any error. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>gangway app</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
  <script>
    const electron = require("electron")
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron

    let sendBtn = document.querySelector("#sendBtn");
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      alert("Alert")
      ipcRenderer.send("key","Gangway Test")
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I start my project I have just one button and it's not working. I dont get any alert. Also I try to post data with ipcRenderer and catch it in main.js with ipcMain but also no any data came. Do I have something wrong with button id?

Comment: Try to update alert to `window.alert()` and see if it works .. also it's better if you use electron built-in dialog and follow new tutorials as a lot of things has been deprecated

Comment: Opening the console would have shown you an actual error.

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use require("electron") inside an HTML file, that has been deprecated. You must have been following an old tutorial.

Please take a look at the [Electron quick start guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start).

EDIT: direct access to the Electron API from the renderer process has been deprecated in newer versions of Electron due to security concerns.

Electron has introduced [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) instead. As mentioned in the documentaton, Context Isolation is a feature that ensures that both your preload scripts and Electron's internal logic run in a separate context to the website you load in a webContents. This is important for security purposes as it helps prevent the website from accessing Electron internals or the powerful APIs your preload script has access to.

You need to create a preload script to expose the ipcRenderer send method to your renderer process.

```
// preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  sendIpcMessage: (channel, data) => {
    ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
  }
});
```

You need to pass this script to the renderer process:

```
// main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('node:path')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  ipcMain.on('key', (event, key) => {
    alert(`received ${key}`)
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})
```

You should now be able to access the method in your renderer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>gangway app</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
  <script>
    const { sendIpcMessage } = window.electron;

    let sendBtn = document.querySelector("#sendBtn");
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert("Alert");
      sendIpcMessage("key", "Gangway Test");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I haven't tested this, but this is the rough idea of what you need to do based on the documentation.

Comment: Right now, this is essentially a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please summarize the relevant information from the link re what to do instead of `require("electron")`. Links rot, and not all sites are accessible to all users (more details in that linked meta Q&A).

Comment: I need electron for ipcRenderer, but also only alert is not working.

Comment: Also I have full install of electron in main.js if you mean it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. You're going to need to slightly change your project structure.

Comment: You forgot the `on` listener on main on your code example.

Comment: These things are life saver, but my problem is not that thing at the moment. My problem is, even without require electron, my alert should work because it's pure javascript in that moment. But my click is not working, not for electron, also not for even just an alert. Is there something wrong with my querySelector or id?

Comment: @Arkellys where? The main.js code has been taken directly from Electron's documentation with zero modifications. I wrote the preload script and modified the renderer code.

Comment: @metkopetru your alert is not working because the code fails on the lines `const electron = require("electron")` and `const {ipcRenderer} = electron` because it can't import electron. Remove those, and the alert should show up.

Comment: @LeonardoG It fixed when I change alert() as window.alert().

Comment: @metkopetru interesting, the line where electron is getting imported should also fail. Do you, perhaps, have nodeIntegration enabled in your Electron config?

Comment: You are right, alert worked but now ipcRenderer is not working. I'll try all what you say and I'll feedback to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255838/discussion-between-metkopetru-and-leonardo-g).

Comment: I tried with all codes you gave. Did not work so far.

Comment: I just realized what @Arkellys meant - are you handling the message anywhere with `ipcMain.on('key', (event, key) => {...})` ? I assumed you had an IPC message handler somewhere already. I have edited my answer and included the handler.

Comment: @metkopetru Please read the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `alert` directly won't work in electron try to use `window.alert() instead`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>gangway app</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
  <script>
    const electron = require("electron")
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron

    let sendBtn = document.querySelector("#sendBtn");
    sendBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
      window.alert("Alert")
      ipcRenderer.send("key","Gangway Test")
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However it's better to use something like [notification](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/notifications) if it's not just for testing.